# Keydown event and timer is not working good together

Tags: c#, windows, timer, keydown

I'm kinda new to both Keys event and timers in my code but for some reason there is this weird bug. (read the last edit)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool start = false;
    Snake ormen = new Snake(10);
    short direction = 3;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Hide();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        start = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        if (start)
        {
            ormen.rita(g);
        }
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                direction = 3;
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                direction = 1;
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                direction = 2;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                direction = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ormen.flytta(direction);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

I also tried to use debug at the key event but it does not even activate until after the time period. Can anyone please tell me why? Also if there are any obvious mistakes i would appreciate it if you could mention them. I have also tried to make the timer interval higher to check if the program can't keep up but it can. (read the last edit)

[EDIT] I don't think it will help but here is the code for the class "Snake". I doubt it's a problem in there but anyways.

```
        private short diameter = 0;
    //0 = Right, 1 = Down, 2 = Left, 3 = Up
    public Snake(short diameter)
    {
        this.diameter = diameter;
        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(new Point(0, 0));
        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(new Point(0 + diameter, 0));
        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(new Point(0 + diameter + diameter, 0));
    }
    Queue<Point> ormensPlatser = new Queue<Point>();
    public void rita(Graphics g)
    {
        Point temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < ormensPlatser.Count; i++)
        {
            temp = ormensPlatser.Dequeue();
            g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), temp.X, temp.Y, diameter, diameter);
            ormensPlatser.Enqueue(temp);
        }
    }
    private void ormNäraKant(short direction,ref Point ormBit)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case 0:
                ormBit.X = ormBit.X + diameter >= 380 ? 0 : ormBit.X + diameter;
                break;
            case 1:
                ormBit.Y = ormBit.Y + diameter >= 360 ? 0 : ormBit.Y + diameter;
                break;
            case 2:
                ormBit.X = ormBit.X - diameter < 0 ? 370 : ormBit.X - diameter;
                break;
            case 3:
                ormBit.Y = ormBit.Y - diameter < 0 ? 350 : ormBit.Y - diameter;
                break;
        }
    }
    public void flytta(short direction)
    {
        Point temp;
        int temp1 = ormensPlatser.Count - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < ormensPlatser.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == temp1)
            {
                switch(direction)
                {
                    case 0:
                        temp = ormensPlatser.Dequeue();
                        ormNäraKant(0, ref temp);
                        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(temp);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        temp = ormensPlatser.Dequeue();
                        ormNäraKant(1, ref temp);
                        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(temp);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        temp = ormensPlatser.Dequeue();
                        ormNäraKant(2, ref temp);
                        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(temp);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        temp = ormensPlatser.Dequeue();
                        ormNäraKant(3, ref temp);
                        ormensPlatser.Enqueue(temp);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ormensPlatser.Dequeue();
                temp = ormensPlatser.Peek();
                ormensPlatser.Enqueue(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[EDIT2] Okey, apparently it wasn't about the time or anything like that, the code worked but i think it has something to do with what slawekwin said in the comments about the focus when the program starts. So the problem is still the same but if I ALT+tab to a another program then back to the snake program it works.

Comment: What's ormen? What does the Invalidate() method do? The keydown event handler is NOT your problem, rule that out. The syntax is fine, it's simply assigning to an Int variable. Going to need a lot more context surrounding the other parts of your code though.

Comment: Don't know if this is the right place to respond to you comment but anyways.. Ormen is the referens from the class named snake and is created at line 4, the invalidate() method makes the screen update as far as I know, that is what I have been taught. I have tried to figure out what exactly it does but nothing so far. But it seems to run the Onpaint function every time i call it.

Comment: all I can think of is that your form has no focus at first so it does not receive the key events

Comment: I think you are probably right, like I said in the last edit I was wrong about the time. It was if i were to tab in and out of the program, so for some reason the key events does not start to input until after I have tab in and out.

Comment: Try explicitly setting focus on load? It doesn't really address the underlying issue, but it could be a workaround for now. If that doesn't work, try focus after the call to the rita method in OnPaint

Comment: hmm.. i went through every propertie the form has and i found a setting called "KeyPrevied" and it was false so i tried to set it to true and it worked.. I don't know if that was some kind of standard thing to always set to true but like I said earlier on in the post, this is really new to to me. Thanks anyways for the help :)

Comment: No problem mate. A much better approach than I was suggesting anyway. Make sure you post that as your answer and mark it as correct to keep your acceptance % high enough on here (helps encourage productive responses in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i finally figure it out, i thought that the problem was with the timer event and the key input event when they worked together but my assumption was wrong. So what i did is that i went through all the properties that the form has and i found a setting called "KeyPrevied" and it was false so i tried to set it to true and it worked :).